# Using aws-sdk.js with require.js in a browser

Tags: requirejs, aws-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how to use the browser-based aws-sdk.js with require.js when building a web app.

If I try to build a class and include aws-sdk in the require.js define, once I try to create an instance and reference the AWS class, it says it is undefined.

For example, I have a function that checks to see if the credentials are an instance of AWS.Credentials and if not, it tries to initialize it with an STS token it retrieves via Rest.
The problem is, the code dies on the if(this.credentials instanceof AWS.Credentials) saying AWS is undefined.  It even dies on my simple check of the needsRefresh.

This is what my define looks like - I'll include the 'needsRefresh' wrapper for an example of the sort of thing that is throwing the Undefined error:

```
define(['require','aws-sdk','jquery'],
    function (require, AWS, $) {

        // Aws helper class
        function AwsHelper() { };

        AwsHelper.prototype = {
            credentials: null,

            tokenNeedsRefresh: function () {
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // errors out on the following line with:                       //
                //   TypeError: Cannot read property 'Credentials' of undefined //
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                if(this.credentials instanceof AWS.Credentials) {
                    return this.credentials.needsRefresh();
                } else return true;
            }
        };
        return AwsHelper;
    }
);
```

I also tried the following format at the top of the file:

```
define(function (require) {
        var AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
            $ = require("jquery");
        /* .. */
```

If I remove all onLoad references to the refresh code running, it will load and I can create an instance. But as soon as I call any function that references the AWS class, it dies.

How do I make sure that AWS class definition is still in global space once an instance is spawned?

Dunno what difference the paths will make (it's finding and loading the code just fine - I can see AWS Class in namespace in the debugger as it's loading but it's not in the namespace on the function call), but added on request:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths: {
        lib: 'lib',
        ImageUploader: 'ImageUploader'
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please show you configuration file paths?

Comment: Just checkered and seems that `aws-sdk` is a NodeJS code, so you should follow this guide: https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html

Comment: There is a node.js version and there is a browser specific version. https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Comment: but there's definitely something weird going on in there - the code is semi minimized, so it's hard to inspect. if I drop console.log() with typeof('AWS') I can see 'object'  for AWS before calling the instance init, but get 'undefined' inside the class method - but '$' is type function in both locations. I even tried manually loading the aws-sdk and putting a set-timeout until typeof(AWS) != undefined before starting the onLoad initializing. no luck there either

Comment: if I try wrapping the minified aws-sdk.js browser code in the 'define(function(require, exports, module) { /* code */ });' as suggested in the manual conversion on that link, I get typeof AWS object  just before the "if instanceof" but it errors on the instanceof with "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object because Credentials is not a property of the AWS object. It just appears to be a proto Object at that point with no properties

Comment: I tried installing the node.js version with npm, and using the instructions for r.js conversion and it says "commonJs.convert: COULD NOT CONVERT: node_modules/aws-sdk/dist-tools/browser-builder.js, so skipping it. Error was: Error: Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: I have no also tried their online custom browser sdk builder and their cli version of same with no better result.

Comment: I've check the source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/master/dist/aws-sdk.js and seems that the AWS itself does not support AMD out of the box, but! There is a 3rd party there included which do support AMD and that might be a problem. Mixing AMD + non AMD in same file is not a good idea... Look for `define.amd` in the source

Comment: what is AMD? I only know that acronym in relation to processors

Comment: https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html

Comment: ahhh gotcha! I found it myself soon after.

Comment: *sigh* none of the 4 threads is getting any help to get closer to a solution

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try to play with this again and seemed to have figured out how I was going about it incorrectly. I have yet to integrate it back into my existing code setup, but I think I have a working solution.

The thing I was doing wrong was I was trying to set up the AWS class so I could load it as a module (thus why I tried wrapping it as the require.js suggested).

Playing with it this time around, I noticed something I hadn't before. I had an AWS that was undefined in the local scope and an other AWS that held the class definition in the global scope.  So it was trying to specify AWS in my define that was creating the local 'null' version:

```
define(
    ["jquery","aws-sdk","dropzone","app/MyUtilities"],
    function ($, AWS, Dropzone, MyUtilities) {
        "use strict";
        function MyClass() {};
        return MyClass;
    }
);
```

jquery and dropzone have whatever is needed to make sure they load that way, but aws-sdk seems to do some of it's own asynchronous loading.  Thus the scope variable in the function is undefined.
Technically, it seems the only thing I needed defined as a module in the function wrapper is my own utilities module. So by switching it to:

```
define(
    ["app/MyUtilities","jquery","aws-sdk","dropzone"],
    function (MyUtilities) {
        "use strict";
        function MyClass() {};
        return MyClass;
    }
);
```

... it seems $ and jquery are defined as needed, Dropzone is defined as needed and AWS is defined as needed. (and I don't get my errors when accessing the static AWS.config or AWS.Credentials definitions as I did before)